# C# property casting of model without loop?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have 3 Model, 1st models has same properties but class name is different. i need to inserts the values into the database from view based on mother of father by selecting RelationshipTypeID dropdownlists selection. so i have created common view for mother/ father. here my intention is to inserts the Mother/ father information by using Parent Model.

```
public class Mother
{
    public int MotherID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
    //---.etc.
}

public class Father
{
    public int  FatherID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
    //---.etc.
}
public class Parent
{
    public int RelationshipTypeID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
    //---.etc.
}
```

Is this possible to use like type casting for without loop through properties?

```
if (parent.RelationshipTypeID == 1)
{
Mother m = (Mother)parent;
db.MotherRepository.Add(m);
db.SaveChanges();
}
if (parent.RelationshipTypeID == 1)
{
Mother m = (Mother)parent;
db.MotherRepository.Add(m);
db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Why not use `class Mother : Parent { ... }` and `class Father : Parent { ... }` ? That way you can switch on type: `if(p is Mother)` or use overloading: `p.Save()`

Comment: @Erno de Weerd can you expand your answer please. what p in if condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this!

```
  public ActionResult Create(ParentsViewModel parent)
    {
        Type ptype = parent.GetType(); 
        PropertyInfo[] ppropinfo = ptype.GetProperties();
        if (parent.RelationshipTypeID == 1)
        {
            Mother m = new Mother();
            Type mtype = m.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] mpropinfo = mtype.GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo minfo in mpropinfo)
            {
                foreach (PropertyInfo pinfo in ppropinfo)
                {
                    if (minfo.Name == pinfo.Name)
                    {
                        minfo.SetValue(m,pinfo.GetValue(parent));
                    }
                }
            }
 var mres = m;
 db.MotherRepository.Add((mres));
 db.SaveChanges();
return View(mres);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
    //---.etc.
}

public class Mother : Parent
{
}

public class Father : Parent
{
}
```

and then:

```
var List<Parent> parents = new List<Parent>();
parents.Add(new Mother());
parents.Add(new Mother());
parents.Add(new Father());
parents.Add(new Father());
parents.Add(new Father());

foreach(var parent in parents)
{
    if(parent is Mother)
    {
        SaveParentAsMother(parent);
    }

    if(parent is Father)
    {
        SaveParentAsFather(parent);
    }
}
```

or use polymorphism by implementing a Save function in Mother and Father with specific code:

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
    public abstract void Save();
    //---.etc.
}

public class Mother : Parent
{
    public override void Save()
    {
         // Save mother details
    }
}

public class Father : Parent
{
    public override void Save()
    {
         // Save father details
    }
}

foreach(var parent in parents)
{
    parent.Save();
}
```

**Extra**

From your comments I gather that you are looking for a way to do the instantiation of a derived object based on a base class object.

```
class Mother : Parent
{
    public Mother(Parent parent)
    {
        this.SSN = parent.SSN;
        this.Name = parent.Name;
    }
}
```

This way you can create a Mother object from a Parent object like this:

```
var mother = new Mother(someParent);
```

Note that this is pretty ugly in my opinion and stresses the fact that it might be better to NOT use instances of a Parent at all. Use Parent as an abstraction not as an object.

```
abstract class Parent
{
}
```

This will prevent you from instantiating a Parent but will still allow you to put behaviour and state that Mothers and Fathers share in the same base class.

Comment: ,thank you for your response. Based on your suggestion i did small modifications in my model and i have another method for Save(), I am trying to assign Mother info which was coming from ParentViewModel object. but not able to assign properly, I require to write very lengthy code. is there any another way to do this.

public class ParentsViewModel : Parent
    {
        //some additional properties
        //---.etc.
    }

public ActionResult Create(ParentsViewModel pvm)
{
    Mother m=(Mother)pvm; // Error here!!
}

Comment: From this tiny bit of code it looks as if you are trying to cast an instance of a base class to a derived class. You can't do that unless you write an explicit cast that fills the extra properties and fields. In general you should not use instances of classes that are not at leaf-level in the hierarchy. For now you could add a constructor to the Mother class that takes a ParentViewModel as parameters and creates a Mother instance based on the ParentViewModel.

Comment: You mean 
 public class Mother:Parent
    {
        public new Mother(Parent p)
        {
            Mother = p;//Error here!!
        }
}

Comment: No. See the addition to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function for code reusability:

```
 public object CompareNameAndSync(object source, object destination)
    {
        Type stype = source.GetType();
        Type dtype = destination.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] spinfo = stype.GetProperties();
        PropertyInfo[] dpinfo = dtype.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo des in dpinfo)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo sou in spinfo)
            {
                if (des.Name == sou.Name)
                {
                    des.SetValue(destination, sou.GetValue(source));
                }
            }
        }
        return destination;

    }
```

**Usage**

```
     public ActionResult Create(ParentsViewModel parent)
    {
            Mother objmother = new Mother();
            objmother =(Mother)CompareNameAndSync(parent, objmother);

            db.MotherRepository.Add(objmother);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View(objmother);
        }
```